# Python: How to import a csv like dat file with a control character delimiter

Tags: python, python-import, csv, control-characters

I have a data file that has the DC4 control character as the delimiter. This is the code I have right now (that I copied from someone else, it is not my code).

```
import csv
with open('Test.dat') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, quotechar='þ', delimiter='')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(f'\t{row[0]} works in the {row[1]} department, and was born in {row[2]}.')
            line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

As you can see the character is displayed by a box, and so far only notepad++ can read it. I have found curses.ascii.isctrl(c), which appears to be able to read that character through python and then read it as a caret? (https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/curses.ascii.html)

I am new to coding and am unsure how I could implement this, or if it will even work for me. Below is a sample of the dat file I am trying to read in text and a screen capture.

```
þIdentifierþþColumn 2þþColumn 3þ
þXX_0012345þþRandom Data 1þþRandom Data 1þ
þXX_0012346þþRandom Data 6þþRandom Data 2þ
þXX_0012347þþRandom Data 1þþRandom Data 3þ
þXX_0012348þþRandom Data 8þþRandom Data 4þ
þXX_0012349þþRandom Data 1þþRandom Data 5þ
þXX_0012345þþRandom Data 9þþRandom Data 1þ
```

[Text File to see the DC4 control character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ5wZ.png)

This is the output when using this code on python 3.6.1. Everything looks good except the Ã¾ character which is how the DC4 character is being read.

```
Column names are ï»¿Ã¾IdentifierÃ¾, Ã¾Column 2Ã¾, Ã¾Column 3Ã¾
    Ã¾XX_0012345Ã¾ works in the Ã¾Random Data 1Ã¾ department, and was born in Ã¾Random Data 1Ã¾.
    Ã¾XX_0012346Ã¾ works in the Ã¾Random Data 6Ã¾ department, and was born in Ã¾Random Data 2Ã¾.
    Ã¾XX_0012347Ã¾ works in the Ã¾Random Data 1Ã¾ department, and was born in Ã¾Random Data 3Ã¾.
    Ã¾XX_0012348Ã¾ works in the Ã¾Random Data 8Ã¾ department, and was born in Ã¾Random Data 4Ã¾.
    Ã¾XX_0012349Ã¾ works in the Ã¾Random Data 1Ã¾ department, and was born in Ã¾Random Data 5Ã¾.
    Ã¾XX_0012345Ã¾ works in the Ã¾Random Data 9Ã¾ department, and was born in Ã¾Random Data 1Ã¾.
Processed 7 lines.
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an escape character for this. DC4 is Ascii 20 (0x14)

```py
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, quotechar='þ', delimiter='\x14')
```

Comment: I tried that and am getting the same output as listed above.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a problem with my computer and not python. Apparently I can't view that character it only shows up as a white box. Is there a way to edit windows 10 to display that character